# Find length of a visible elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, children

Hi all I need to find the length of all the li elements which has display block only. How can this be possible using jQuery. I have a category menu block which has more link at the bottom which when clicked will displays the all categories.The Bottom link now turn to Less which when clicked displays less items.
 Here is the code.

```
var list = $('.menu-categories-list ul li:gt(3)');
        list.hide();
        $('#ClickMore').click(function() {
            list.slideToggle(400);
            if( $(this).parent().prev().children().length < 1 ) {
                $(this).html('Less...');
            }
            else {
                $(this).html('More...');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

YOu can have a look at the [link](http://www.aussieshoppingbuyinggroup.com.au/home.php). The categories block on the left side

Comment: Or perhaps the number of visible items?

Comment: the number of visible li's length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
$('.menu-categories-list ul li:visible').size()
```

in condition:

```
if ( $('.menu-categories-list ul li:visible').size() >= 4 ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: how to write this in if condition?

Comment: the `.size()` method returns integer

Comment: I have tried this but this doesn't work. For the first time it works fine. Shows more link when tiems are 4. When click on more all items displays and less link shows. But after that less link doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming from Google...

The `.size()` method has been [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/size/) as of jQuery 1.8, use `.length` instead:

```
$('.menu-categories-list ul li:visible').length
```

Will return an integer value depicting the number of visible `li` elements that are children of `.menu-categories > ul`

*Written as an answer as I don't have enough rep to comment on Teneff's answer*