# validate only visible elements in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to validate the form elements on click next buttoon in step form. I am using the folllowing code which is validating all the hidden fields also. Need help. Thanks in advance..

Here is my Code :

```
$('.msf-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {                                 
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;


    parent_fieldset.find('.is_required').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
            $(".error-messages-slct").text("Please Select an option in the list").fadeIn();
            next_step = false;
        }
        else{
       $(this).focus().css('border','0px solid #F44336');
       $(".error-messages-slct").empty().fadeOut();

    }
    });

    parent_fieldset.find('.is_required1').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');
            $(".error-messages-slct1").text("Select an option in the list").fadeIn();
            next_step = false;
        }
        else{
       $(this).focus().css('border','0px solid #F44336');
       $(".error-messages-slct1").empty().fadeOut();

    }
    });

    if( next_step ) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `:visible` after the selectors. Use this reference..

[Use it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334573/find-length-of-a-visible-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Nice one, didn't think of this. Side question: Is this functionally different from the display property? (I think I remember visibility:hidden and display:none being different)

Comment: @SREagle https://jsfiddle.net/zqpswxbv/ Here you can see the difference :-)

Comment: Thanks alot for the example, this confirms my half forgotten 'knowledge'. But I just found out that jQuery's .fadeIn/.fadeOut set the display property too, so it's irrelevant for the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going over each element of class '.is_required1' and '.is_required', you need to do it only for these element(s) which is(are) currently visible. You can use an additional class for this, or query the display property.

Taking minksmnm's suggestion into account, you could use `find('.is_required:visible')` instead of ``find('.is_required')` to only select the visible elements. Otherwide your find also gets the hidden ones and validates them too.

Comment: visible elements are those which comes after selection of different radio buttons. On every different radio there are different select box and its validating all selection box under different radio buttons